# issue with deleting rows in python sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql
import os
sea_level_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\SeaLevel.csv", skiprows=3)
display(sea_level_df)
conn = sql.connect(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\sqlite\db\z.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
s = sea_level_df.to_sql('v', conn)
cur.commit(s)
conn.close()

class database:
    
    def __init__(self):
        conn = sql.connect('z')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        
    def create_table():
        conn = sql.connect('z')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        n = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS k( 
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        year INTEGER NOT NULL
        sea_level INTEGER NOT NULL)
        ;"""
        cur.execute(n)
        conn.commit()
        print("table created")
        conn.close()
            
    def insert():
        conn = sql.connect(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\sqlite\db\z.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        query = ("""INSERT INTO v VALUES (1223, 2022, -17.89, 0, 0, 0);""")
        cur.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        t = ("""SELECT * FROM v;""")
        w = cur.execute(t).fetchall()
        print(w)
        conn.close()
              
    def remove():
        conn = sql.connect(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\sqlite\db\z.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        g = ("""DELETE FROM v
        WHERE index = 1221;""")
        cur.execute(g)
        conn.commit()
        b = ("""SELECT * FROM v;""")
        q = cur.execute(b).fetchall()
        print(q)
        conn.close()
        
    def search():
        conn = sql.connect(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\sqlite\db\z.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        x = ("""SELECT * FROM v WHERE index = 1221;""")
        h = cur.execute(x).fetchall()
        print(h)
        conn.close()
        
    def test():
        conn = sql.connect('z')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        u = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM z;""").fetchall()
        print(u)
```

So I'm having trouble with the functions titled "remove" and "search". I get these errors respectively:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [76], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 database.remove()

Input In [75], in database.remove()
     33 cur = conn.cursor()
     34 g = ("""DELETE FROM v
     35 WHERE index = 1221;""")
---> 36 cur.execute(g)
     37 conn.commit()
     38 b = ("""SELECT * FROM v;""")

OperationalError: near "index": syntax error
```

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [77], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 database.search()

Input In [75], in database.search()
     45 cur = conn.cursor()
     46 x = ("""SELECT * FROM v WHERE index = 1221;""")
---> 47 h = cur.execute(x).fetchall()
     48 print(h)
     49 conn.close()

OperationalError: near "index": syntax error
```

and the data is basically a csv stored within a dataframe stored within an sqlite database. for the remove function I'm just trying to remove a row of data and for the search function, I'm just trying to pull up a specific index.

Answer (score 0):

Since "index" is a reserved keyword as listed [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), have you tried adding brackets [index] or rename this field if you can ? Maybe something like [v_id] would be a better choice in my opinion.